# Can't animate properly an attachable I'm making for an add-on

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

Hi coders and all smart people here xD, I joined because I need some help with the programming of an add-on im making for Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, so basically Im trying to make a "shield", right now I just want it to be used in the main hand and off hand, I dont want it to block attacks, etc. So using Blockbench, I decided to edit some files, but I got stuck in the animations part, here you have what I did:

My attachable.json:

```
{
    "format_version": "1.10.0",
    "minecraft:attachable": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "dvstarowo:escudo_de_oro",
            "render_controllers": ["controller.render.armor"],
            "materials": {
                "default": "entity_alphatest_glint",
                "enchanted": "entity_alphatest_glint"
            },
            "textures": {
                "default": "textures/entity/attachable/escudo_de_oro",
                "enchanted": "textures/misc/enchanted_item_glint"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "default": "geometry.escudo_de_oro"
            },
            "animations": {
                "first_person_hold": "animation.escudo_de_oro.first_person_hold",
                "third_person_hold": "animation.escudo_de_oro.third_person_hold",
                "off_hand_hold": "animation.escudo_de_oro.off_hand_hold"
            },
            "scripts": {
                "animate": [
                    {
                        "first_person_hold": "c.is_first_person"
                    },
                    {
                        "third_person_hold": "!c.is_first_person"
                    },
                    {
                        "off_hand_hold": "c.item_slot != 'main_hand'"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my animation.json

```
{
    "format_version": "1.8.0",
    "animations": {
        "animation.escudo_de_oro.first_person_hold": {
            "loop": true,
            "bones": {
                "root_item": {
                    "rotation": [66, 60, -60],
                    "position": [3, 23, 4]
                },
                "Escudo": {
                    "rotation": [117.5, 47.5, 0],
                    "position": [-0.82178, 27.33324, 7.32329]
                }
            }
        },
        "animation.escudo_de_oro.off_hand_hold": {
            "loop": true,
            "bones": {
                "root_item": {
                    "rotation": [66, 60, -60],
                    "position": [3, 23, 4]
                },
                "Escudo": {
                    "rotation": [53.98411, 51.72089, -81.96172],
                    "position": [7.84447, 38.25722, -18.10431]
                }
            }
        },
        "animation.escudo_de_oro.third_person_hold": {
            "loop": true,
            "bones": {
                "root_item": {
                    "rotation": [90, 0, 0],
                    "position": [0.5, 22.5, -0.5]
                },
                "Escudo": {
                    "position": [0, 16, -5]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first two "first_person_hold" and "third_person_hold" work perfectly fine when I test them in Minecraft, they places are like in Blockbench, but the "off_hand_hold" doesn't, its place is like up the skin head and rotated, I noticed that I used another type of Molang thing, but I don't understand why it affects the position of my model, if someone can help me to understand and to find a way to make it work, I would really appreciate it :)